# Triggering issue with Yongnuo 600ex-rt speedlight

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

I have had a Yongnuo 600EX-RT speedlight (knock-off of Canon 600EX-RT) for some time, and recently purchased a Yongnuo YN-E3-RT wireless trigger (knock-off of Canon SN-E3-RT) to give me off-camera flash capability. The problem I'm having is with flash triggering with the speedlight set up in Group A or Group B.

If I set both the trigger and the speedlight to Group A, **or** if I set them both to Group B, then I don't get a triggered flash.

I have success only with: **(1)** both the trigger and speedlight set to Group C, or **(2)** the trigger set to ALL and the speedlight set to  Group C.

I'm trying to determine if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a problem with the transmitter or a problem with the speedlight.

Anyone have any insights?

Comment: In addition to the radio channel and group letters matching, have you checked to see what the wireless ID number is set for both the trigger and flash, respectively?

Comment: Both are set to the same ID and channel. I shouldn't be able to get any flash at all otherwise, and I do get flashes on Group C.